# Python HMAC OpenSSL equivalent

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, hmac, sha512

Hi I have the following code written in Python

```
import hashlib
import base64

def sign(secret_in_base64):
    secret_in_bytes = base64.b64decode(secret_in_base64.encode('ascii'))
    signature = hmac.new(secret_in_bytes, "secret_message".encode("utf-8"), digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
    return base64.b64encode(signature.digest())
```

What is the equivalent `openssl` command and option that I can use so that it can generate the same base64 string as the above Python method?

I have tried to `echo "secret_message" | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac $secret_in_base64 | base64` but that doesn't generate the same result. Is there something I missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty was that Python is accepting `bytes` as key after b64decode `secret_in_base64`. In order to do the same  with `openssl`, we will need to use `xxd` to convert the binary into a hex and specify -macopt hexkey option to openssl.

```sh
hex_secret=$(echo $secret_in_base64 | base64 -d | xxd -p | tr -d '\n')
echo "secret_message" | openssl dgst -sha512 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:"$hex_secret" -binary | base64 | tr -d '\n'
```